# Prism and MVVM databinding from modules to main shell datacontext

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

Have some experience with WPF and databinding, but completely new to PRISM and MVVM.

I'm working on Prism application where I have a shell and multiple modules.

In my previous WPF application I had a single window datacontext (with all objects I need) which I could then simply databind from any usercontrol inside my window.

In the context of the Prism, what is the proper way to have a single datacontext, let's we call it ShellViewModel and then for all modules to bind to its' objects and properties? So if there is a change in one property in ShellViewModel which is caused by one module, another module can detected that by databinding and then maybe trigger a style?

Probably there is a simple way to do this but I'm new to PRISM and MVVM and completely confused how we can do properly bindings especially when there are multiple modules involved?

Also any source code and examples would be great.

Comment: Having a single datacontext for everything to bind to sounds a lot like the god object anti-pattern and there are usually better ways to solve it with lesser dependencies (which is one of the points of having modules in the first place). Usually every view has it's own datacontext and communication between those is managed with e.g. events or with some intermediate class which is passed to all the pieces of code which need to communicate (possibly using some DI framework like MEF).

Comment: Ok, so I should decouple my datacontext across multiple modules? So in this case, in the Shell window I have single 'Save' button, how do I disable it if there is error in any of the modules views? And how do I re-enable it after error has gone. 'Save' button should also save all changes in all of modules views and in the main shell.

Comment: There are few ways to communicate between ViewModels, one is to have PubSub event(s), so your shell would listen to this. Another is as @stijn said having a class that is passed as DI to each ViewModel, or maybe pass a callback action through navigation parameters, then anytime you need to update this button invoke it.

Comment: Ok I will check this Pub/Sub method as I already know some of it. About the other method, with class passed as DI to each ViewModel, do you have any reference or sample I could check on? Is that class passed to all modules ViewModules as singleton (single instance of Shell ViewModel?) I'm new to Prism, Mvvm and DI so my questions are absolutely beginning... Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. I think you'll get more responses when asking a practical example (like the enabling/disabling of the Save button you mention) so I'd suggest to delete this question and ask a new one, wwith something more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single source of data, make it available to all your view models as a service.

Register it as a singleton, so that all view models get the same instance. If you need the service to push updates to the view models, make it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and let the view models observe that (done best through a [`PropertyObserver`](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/)).

Remember that the view model is the data context of the view, and that it should only communicate data and events between the view and the data source a.k.a. model, but should not own data itself.

Comment: I have read your answer not once, but multiple times. And every time I read it, again and again, I start to thinking that I understand what you mean... When you said singleton and ViewModels, I can inject it in constructor of every ViewModel, and maybe use Mef for that? (after adding to  AggregateCatalog in Bootstrapper)

Comment: Exactly, wether you use mef or unity or ninject, that's what the di container is for: providing each instance with its required dependencies. And your view models should depend on a service, and the container takes care (if told to do so) that all view models get the same service instance. Prism really helps with this as view models get their dependencies automatically when constructed by the view model locator.