# Global variable concept in PRISM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm investigating to use PRISM 6.2 for an application that will have a similar UI to Visual Studio. It also will be docking window with multiple document interface. I currently have a toolbar region and a docking region. I have managed to get some of the docking working with a custom region adapter.

The design problem I'm facing now is how to share an object globally.

The concrete situation I have is that the user can open a 'solution' from a file menu. That 'solution' is then needed in a 'Solution explorer'VM, in a 'class view'VM,... I can get my head around it up to the moment I start thinking about opening a new 'solution', then all views should be updated with the new solution. Closing and recreating seems like a crappy solution.

I was thinking of having an open command in the ShellVM that modifies a solution property in the regioncontext of the docking region. Each toolitem can then monitor a notifypropertychanged on that property to update. Or, if not opened yet, use that property on creation.

I'm however not sure about this setup. It sounds a bit like some "god object".

Another approach I have found is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258147/4169986

> Have a single source of data, make it available to all your view models as a service.

But I am not grasping how to combine that with INotifyPropertyChanged when a new 'solution' is opened.

What would be and advisable PRISM way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a shared singleton service that you inject your view models with: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single source of data can provide you with the data instead of being the data itself. Think of something like this:

```
interface ISolutionProvider : INotifiyPropertyChanged
{
    ISolution TheCurrentSolution
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

All your view models that need the current `ISolution` don't get that injected but the `ISolutionProvider`, and they access the solution via `_solutionProvider.TheCurrentSolution`.

If someone changes the current solution, the `ISolutionProvider` fires the `PropertyChanged` event and the view models notice the changes and push them to their views.

Note that `ISolutionProvider.TheCurrentSolution` has no setter - that's because I'd recommend putting that functionality in a different interface. Most of the consumers of the solution will either want to read the solution *or* close/open/change it, but not both.

Also, when monitoring `ISolutionProvider.NotifyPropertyChanged` from the view model, you need to make sure to use weak events (preferably) or at least disconnect the event handlers when the view model dies, because the event would otherwise keep the view model alive (creating a memory leak). This little [gem](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/) comes really handy here...